# Trying to write a C program to bubble sort 25 words from a 2 dimensional array alphabetically

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, bubble-sort

I figured out how to read in the strings, but I'm not sure how to use bubble sort to arrange them alphabetically. This is what I have to far. I keep receiving the error "Segmentation fault (core dumped).

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <string.h> 

#define NUM 25   /* number of strings */
#define LEN 1000  /* max length of each string */

     main()
        {
          char Strings[NUM][LEN];
          int i, j;
          char tempValue;

          printf("Please enter %d strings, one per line:\n", NUM);

          for(i=0; i<NUM-1; i++)
          {    
           fgets(Strings[i], LEN-2, stdin);
          }

          for(i=0; i<NUM-1; i++)
          {
            for(j=0; j<LEN-2; j++)
            {
              if(Strings[i][j] < Strings[i+1][j]) 
              {
                tempValue = Strings[i][j];
                Strings[i][j] = Strings[i + 1][j];
                Strings[i + 1][j] = tempValue;


              }
            }
          }

        }
```

Comment: You're going to need some swap code.

Comment: You either need to use `strcmp` to compare two strings, or you need to write your own string compare function. Trying to nest a string compare inside of a bubble sort (without calling a function to compare the strings) just results in a whole lot of spaghetti.

Comment: Also your conditions in your `for` loops are one-off. E.g. with `NUM`: the `for` loop should be `for (i = 0; i < NUM; i++)`. For example, if you set `NUM` to 3, then the `for` loop must let `i` take the values 0, 1, and 2 (so 3 steps) and not `NUM-1` which would let `i` take 2 steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use strcmp

```
if(strcmp(Strings[i], Strings[i+1]) > 0) 
{
    //swap elements
}
```

it will basically compare chars in strings and first not matching pair of chars, if it has greater value in first string passed to function, it will return 1.

Comment: Is there any way to do this without C library functions for the comparing code?

Comment: Well u can implement the same thing yourself (it's easy), but i don't see the point.